# Stormpath Spring Boot redirect loop

Tags: angularjs, redirect, spring-boot, stormpath, redirect-loop

Using Stormpath and Spring Boot (based on [this tutorial](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/quickstart.html)), after I've started my server and successfully logged in with my credentials everything works fine. However when I exit the browser and try to open my application I get a redirect loop.

A [minimal example is available here as an archive](https://gist.github.com/kohanyirobert/607fba9f85ebd059801c/raw/2437d3a8740629a594747ff6e4de6b81fee8e0e3/spring-boot-stormpath-redirect-loop-demo.tar.gz). It's a Gradle project. `cd` into the directory inside the archive and start the server with `./gradlew bootRun`. The app will be accessible at http://localhost:8080. A Stormpath API key is needed for this. Register, [get an API key](http://docs.stormpath.com/rest/quickstart/#get-an-api-key) and copy the apiKey-XXX.properties file to `~/.stormpath/apiKey.properties`. This way Spring Boot will pick up the file and use it by default (only when you have a single application defined in Stormpath, that is).

Login, then quit your browser (on a Mac don't just close it with the red button, use command-q or right click on the browser's icon and quit it). Restart it and try access http://localhost:8080 once again. That's when I get the redirect loop. Tried it on Mac and Windows, Firefox and Chrome, same happens.

If I open the developer console I can see that first I'm redirected to the login page (fair enough), then I'm redirected to `/` (wierd) and so on...

When I login the first time I can see that a cookie with the name `account` is created for localhost and a `JSESSIONID` too. When I restart the browser the `account` cookie is intact and `JSESSIONID` is regenerated by the server. So I guess this behavior is related to the fact that `JSESSIONID` is bound to the login session or something.

Is there a way to configure this behavior? After a browser restart the user should be a) still logged in or b) be able to log again. Any idea?

<sub>Also, on a side note, I'm using an AngularJS app as my frontend. I don't think that should make any difference, but I though it could be important (the example app contains some AngularJS hello world code for this end).</sub>

## Update

The issue was flagged as a bug by Stormpath and after the release of `com.stormpath.spring:stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter:1.0.RC8.1` it is now fixed. [See the following answer and the comments for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34888978/433835).

Comment: Is there a conflict with SpringSecurity?

Comment: There's a bug in Tomcat 8.0.30 that can cause behaviour like this. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4937 for some more details and a possible workaround that might be worth a try

Comment: I wasn't able to run your app yet, but in the [quickstart](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/quickstart.html) they said you should set a `stormpath.application.href` in your `application.properties` if you have more than one API key - and I can't find that configuration in the linked sources

Comment: @Raffaele Check [this link](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/quickstart.html#any-problems) on the possible settings.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I don't think it's a Tomcat issue. On my dev machine I've an actual app which uses Jetty instead of Tomcat and I've experienced the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Stormpath's Java Developer Evangelist.

I was not able to replicate the behavior using your zip file.

However, we *have* seen this before. It's related to browsers aggressively caching 302 redirects, especially against `localhost`.

Here's a reference that speaks to the issue in Chrome: http://kmarsden.com/chrome-redirect-cache/

Clearing cache should take care of the problem.

And, this would *never* happen in a production environment.

[gif of Firefox interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUx3N.gif)

Comment: Thanks for the response, will look into the caching thing. Already thought about - I've disabled caching in Chrome's developer toolbar, there's a setting to do that, but to no avail. I'll try again maybe I overlooked something. Also, would you mind trying it in Chrome quickly? :)

Comment: I can replicate your behavior if I enable Firefox's 'clear history on exit' feature. With that the `JSESSIONID` and the `account` cookies are cleared and when I restart the browser I have to log back in. Which is fine I guess, but enabling clearing the cookies on exit in Firefox (for every host) is kind of *not good* in my opinion. :/ Also, using Chrome's dev settings to clear the cache does not work.

Comment: I've confirmed the behavior you are seeing using a fresh chrome install. I've logged an issue here: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/issues/450 I believe the issue is that the account cookie identifies you as being logged into Stormpath, but it is disassociated from the Spring Security context. Spring Security redirects `/` to `/login` (as it should). Stormpath thinks you're logged in, so `/login` redirects you back to `/`. I will follow up once the issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, will monitor the ticket as well as this question.

Comment: pending review of [this PR](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/pull/451), I will be releasing 1.0.RC8.1 later tonight. This addresses the redirect loop.

Comment: Hey Kohányi: I've released Java SDK, version `1.0.RC8.1`. It should propagate to Maven Central within the hour. Thanks for bringing this to our attention!